# resources don't contain package for resource number

Tags: android, resources

I have looked at all the other answers to this question, but none of them have worked for me.  What package identifier is it talking about?  I am using R.drawable.blah and R is created with the correct package as far as I can see.

Any ideas what could be causing these warnings.  They don't cause a problem on my device, but they might on another.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try cleaning the project (in Eclipse, use Clean from the Project menu. In Ant, try "ant clean"). If that doesn't work, please post some examples of how you're calling resources in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Usually it is because of some Eclipse hickups. Try Project -> Clean...

Comment: I tried cleaning in eclipse (I don't use ANT at the moment).  It didn't make any difference.  However, I noticed that these messages only come up when deploying from eclipse, they don't happen when running the app from the device manually.  I think the act of eclipse uninstalling / reinstalling the package is causing the warning.  I see "Got android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED" info message after the Resource Errors.